# How to generate custom date time from Unix timestamp using PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

How do I convert a Unix timestamp to the following custom date format: '28-Jan-2017'?
Below is my attempt.

```
$unixT = 1532728800;

$date = new DateTime();
$date -> setTimestamp($unixT);
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

With above I get  '28-07-2017'.

Comment: try to use `d-M-Y` note capital `M`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: @LLya Bursov, thanks for your help man. If you put it down as an answer I can set it as the solution

Comment: `DateTime::format()` uses the same formats as `date()` - so have a look at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

Please use capital (M) instead of small (m).

```
echo $date->format('d-M-Y');
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e13ac81ea95ab55ee731841183d344a9de8fdf5b)